# How can I disable the same origin policy iframe port restriction in firefox 48?

Tags: security, firefox, same-origin-policy

Firefox 48 has a new security restriction that blocks javascript calls in iframes if the port is different. Is there a way to disable this in about:config or some other setting (basically disable the same origin policy)?

I work on an enterprise website. The site has a page like a.site.com:12345 which has an iframe b.site.com:12346. We are setting document.domain=".site.com" for both pages. The b.site.com iframe is able to make javascript calls to the parent window and access the a.site.com dom. This is working for all current versions of browsers and works in firefox 47 and lower. The new firefox 48 does not allow these calls since the ports are different.

Our production environment is fine since in prod all servers use the same SSL port but in our test environment all the servers use different/non standard SSL ports. This means we are not able to test firefox 48 without moving code to production and is halting testing efforts. While disabling the same origin policy is not desirable it is better than not testing at all. How can I disable this new security restriction?

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin), setting `document.domain` for both sites should set the port to `null`, thus giving the frames access to each other. The only thing I can think of is that `site.com` could be required rather than `.site.com`, but that's just a guess...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did already try using site.com but that did not help. Will look to see if there is some way to set the port to null. There is no issue on IE  its only Firefox 48+ that seems to have the issue. I'm really wondering if it is a ff 48 bug.

Comment: If you're following the exact instructions on MDN and getting different results, I'd go ahead and report it as a bug. What's the worst than can happen?

Comment: I also started thinking along the same lines. The documentation on mozillas own website says setting document.domain in parent and child frames makes the port null. On a hunch I downloaded the nightly developer firefox 49 build which is scheduled for release Sep 13th. lo and behold everything works. I cant find the exact bug in their tracker but I'm sure this is FF48 bug now and looks like it is fixed in 49! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed in firefox 49 nightly beta build. Looks like this was a firefox 48 issue alone.